# Dreamweaver Phonegap Android Emulation Problem

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, emulation, dreamweaver

I'm having problems using the emulator for dreamweaver using the Jquery Mobile(phonegap) template.  Specifically the emulator starts but the app doesn't load and there is no app icon for the app either.  When i build and emulate the message "Dreamweaver is unable to open Tour Finder, please consult the build log.  I have dreamweaver 5.5 and updates installed.  I have the up to date android sdk and sdk tools installed also.  I am able to emulate apps through eclipse.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is the build log:

```
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd D:\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
D:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
____________________
</DW>
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *

* daemon started successfully *

List of devices attached 



Launching the Android emulator
<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd D:\ANDROI~1\tools
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c "D:\android-sdk\tools\emulator.exe -partition-size 1024 -cpu-delay     0 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_2.3.3_API_10_WVGA_480x800"
____________________
</DW>
WARNING: no splash screen was specified in app settings. using default.

<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd C:\Users\David\Desktop\COMEXP~1.TOU
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /u /c C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1\bin\ant.bat debug
____________________
</DW>
Buildfile: C:\Users\David\Desktop\COMEXP~1.TOU\build.xml

[setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 13

[setup] Project Target: Google APIs

[setup] Vendor: Google Inc.

[setup] Platform Version: 2.2

[setup] API level: 8

[setup] 

[setup] ------------------

[setup] Resolving library dependencies:

[setup] No library dependencies.

[setup] 

[setup] ------------------

[setup] 

[setup] WARNING: Attribute minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml (2) is lower than the project target API level (8)

[setup] 

[setup] Importing rules file: tools\ant\main_rules.xml



-debug-obfuscation-check:



-set-debug-mode:



-compile-tested-if-test:



-pre-build:



-dirs:

 [echo] Creating output directories if needed...



-aidl:

 [echo] Compiling aidl files into Java classes...



-renderscript:

 [echo] Compiling RenderScript files into Java classes and RenderScript bytecode...



-resource-src:

 [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...



-pre-compile:



compile:

[javac] D:\android-sdk\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:385: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set,    defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

[javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\David\Desktop\COMEXP~1.TOU\bin\classes



-post-compile:



-obfuscate:



-dex:

 [echo] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Users\David\Desktop\COMEXP~1.TOU    \bin\classes.dex...



-package-resources:

 [echo] Packaging resources

 [aapt] Creating full resource package...

[aapt.exe] Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.



-package-debug-sign:

[apkbuilder] Creating tour_finder-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...



debug:

 [echo] Running zip align on final apk...

 [echo] Debug Package: C:\Users\David\Desktop\COMEXP~1.TOU\bin\tour_finder-debug.apk



BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 13 seconds


<DW>
____________________
set ANT_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\CONFIG~1\NATIVE~1\APACHE~1
set ANDROID_HOME=D:\android-sdk
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\ADOBED~2.5\JDK
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cd D:\ANDROI~1\PLATFO~2
D:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
____________________
</DW>

Waiting for Android emulator to bootERROR: failed to launch Android emulator
```

Comment: I was able to get round this by manually opening the emulator through the android sdk manager first then using the build and emulate option in dreamweaver.

Comment: Can you please be more specific ... I am on Dreamweaver CS5 and downloaded all SDK and Phonegap and trying a simple HelloWorld.. getting same error as yourself.. how did you do this? You should answer your own question with much more detail

Answer (score 0):

I've came accross with the same problem.

I've runned into this solution: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3997853 and it works! However i have to have the emulator fully booted and running before i do "Build and Emulate" in DW (or just do 2x "Build and Emulate").